# How to remove extra spaces and new lines in a string?

Tags: java, arrays, string

I have a string variable s which is like a combination of passages.
For example,

```
Passages provides funeral and burial products.

Our products are meant to align with your values and bring you comfort.

Our products allow you to offer personalization , flexibility and innovative choices, helping you provide services to a wider range of customers.
```

I have to make that string variable of this form:

```
Passages provides funeral and burial products. Our products are meant to align with your values and bring you comfort. Our products allow you to offer personalization, flexibility and innovative choices, helping you provide services to a wider range of customers.
```

Plus, extra spaces between words are to be removed(or between a '.' and the first line of the word)  an converted to a single space and any number of spaces before ',','.' or ';' is to be removed.

I am a newbie in java. Can anybody tell me how can it be done?

Comment: Take a look at regular expressions in Java.

Comment: Your rules appear to be inconsistent.  If you edit your question with _exact_ formatting rules you might get a usable answer.

Comment: You can iterate through the string and copy all character which are not \n or any other character by using conditions.

Comment: I have implemented all the rules except that how to remove all the spaces between a word and a ',','.' or ';'(word appears first)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with this: (@Criti's way)

```
    String s = "Passages provides funeral and burial products.\n"
            + "Our products are meant to align with your values and bring you comfort.\n"
            + "Our products allow you to offer personalization , flexibility and innovative choices, helping you provide services to a wider range of customers.";

    s = s.replaceAll("\\s*\\.\\s*\n\\s*", ". ");
    s = s.replaceAll("\\s*,\\s*", ", ");
    s = s.replaceAll("\\s*;\\s*", "; ");
    System.out.println(s);
```

Output:

```
Passages provides funeral and burial products. Our products are meant to align with your values and bring you comfort. Our products allow you to offer personalization, flexibility and innovative choices, helping you provide services to a wider range of customers.
```

Comment: The space between a word and '.' or ';' is not being removed in your solution.eg.: 'this is cool . that is hot.' is not getting changed to 'this is cool. that is hot.'

Comment: Edited; Could You try again?

Answer (score 4):

I'm a big fan of the Apache Commons Lang library - the `StringUtils` class (with its null-safe functions) has saved me countless hours over the years. Not surprisingly, `StringUtils` has a function that does what you're looking for: [`StringUtils.normalizeSpace(String str)`](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-3.3.2/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html#normalizeSpace%28java.lang.String%29)

From the API:

> The function returns the argument string with whitespace normalized by
>   using trim(String) to remove leading and trailing whitespace and then
>   replacing sequences of whitespace characters by a single space.

Answer (score 3):

The only problem with Regexs is they can be quite slow. IF you are willing to use external libraries, try the Google Guava Library and its CharMatcher

```java
CharMatcher.whitespace().collapseFrom("Hello There\nMy name is Fred   ", ' '))
```

This will convert the whitespace to a single space, AND collapse multiple sequences of whitespace into a single sequence.

Answer (score 1):

`string.replaceAll("\n", "").replaceAll("\\s+", " ")`

Answer (score 0):

One way is to parse the String variable character by character.
For example

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
String toBeParse = "...";
for (int i = 0; i < toBeParse.length(); i++) {
    if (toBeParse.charAt(i) == condition) {
        sb.append(toBeParse.charAt(i));
    }
}
String result = sb.toString();
```

Another way is to use regular expresions:

```
toBeParse.replaceAll(yourRegexString, replacement);
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
str = str.replaceAll("\\.\\s+(\\w)", ". $1");
```